# Find Elements by data-bind [Findsby]

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to click an element by data-bind attribute and using the FindsBy attribute. 
I also tried to implement it by following [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2014/07/09/use-selenium-to-find-elements-by-knockoutrsquos-data-bind.aspx), but could not really get it work.

is it possible to use Findsby? something like this

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Databind, Using = "click: AddAttachment ")]
public IWebElement btnUpload{ get; set;}
```

html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bind="click: AddAttachment ">Upload</button>
```

Comment: have you tried a google search on the `FindBy` attribute to see examples on how to use as well as call..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how your setup is but mine would look like this:

```
   [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//button[contains(text(), 'Upload')]")]
    private readonly IWebElement _upload = null;
```

Then create a method to use it.

```
    public void ClickUpload()
    {
        Browser.Click(_upload);
    }
```

Comment: This worked out of the box. Thank you for that.
Did not know that you could use the buttons xpath like that. this will solve a lot of problems i had earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find by a `data-` attribute's value you can use the following:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//button[@data-bind = 'click: AddAttachment']")]
```

Comment: Thank you! This will also help me and probably others with the same noob problems ;)