# Selenium C# - How to get value of disabled text field with no value attribute

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a input type text which is disabled and has no value attribute.

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- ko if: HierarchyId() != SystemHierarchy.Store -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="disable: HierarchyId() == SystemHierarchy.Enterprise || IsAccessible() === false, value: ShortName" disabled="">
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: HierarchyId() == SystemHierarchy.Store --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

On the UI, this input field has a default disabled value, say '429'. I need this value 429 but not able to fetch since there is no value attribute in it.

Comment: Can you provide some code example of your current logic?
Also, you have to fetch the element after the binding event. Otherwise its value and other bound properties will not be fetched.

Comment: I have tried element.getAttribute("innerHTML") but it returns blank

Comment: Please post the complete markup with '429' in it. Ideally the surrounding HTML markup will contain this value somewhere.

Comment: Can you please try `element.Text`?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh updated the post. thats all in the HTML i have for this element

Comment: @Rostech element.Text return blank again

Comment: @BishwaroopChakraborty Oh, I'm sorry. Can you please try again with `element.getAttribute("value")`?

Comment: it returns blank

Comment: Can you please  provide some c# code?

Comment: You can also use `JavascriptExecutor` and get the value in the input with `$('.form-control').val()`. But it is important to show us how you are selecting the element.

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML is using Knockout JS to bind the values. You can find the element text by using Xpath of the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class, 'form-control') and contains(@data-bind, 'disable: HierarchyId')]")]").Text;
```

Note: I tried to use the closest xpath of your element. You might need to try and this out, and change the Xpath as if required.

Also refer-
http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2014/07/09/use-selenium-to-find-elements-by-knockoutrsquos-data-bind.aspx
[Find Elements by data-bind [Findsby]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104672/find-elements-by-data-bind-findsby)
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/10342/how-to-find-element-using-contains-in-xpath